# Adding a Toolbar doesn't work

Tags: java, android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I'm trying to integrate a Toolbar to my existing App. Android Studio doesn't show any errors but the App just wont work. It blinks out for half a second or so but then finishes with an info window on my phone which says that my app has been closed.
What do I do wrong/what is the problem?

Here's my whole code:

MapActivity.Java

```
    package com.example.testingmapingmarker23;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;



import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;



import static com.example.testingmapingmarker23.R.id.map;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        final Toolbar customToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    }





}
```

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testingmapingmarker23"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.4.0"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

My device is a OnePlus One with Android 6.0.1 and API 23 on it

Stack Trace with changed Toolbar:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.testingmapingmarker23, PID: 2905
                                                                             Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo, iconPack:system, fontPkg:com.cyngn.hexo, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo}
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testingmapingmarker23/com.example.testingmapingmarker23.MapsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:359)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                 at com.example.testingmapingmarker23.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:35)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Do you have proper permissions(Internet & Location) enabled, because in API 23 and above we need to ask users permission at run-time to make some of our features work. If you have those, could you please update with the stack trace of the error.

Comment: Yes, I gave the permissions for 'access_fine_location' and 'internet' in the androidmanifest.xml . You can see the stack trace above

Comment: `setSupportActionbar(toolbar)` in `onCreate()` of your `MainActivity()`

Comment: That is not a stack trace, its part of `gradle console`. Please see https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces.html and update your question with proper stack trace

Comment: @FirozMemon is updated

Comment: @Dennis I tried to add Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar); but it doesn't know 'setSupportActionBar'

Comment: Kindly have a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are few things you need to keep in mind in order to display your own `AppBar`/`Toolbar`

kindly copy this code to your `.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="1080dp"
    android:layout_height="1920dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1720px"
        tools:context="com.example.testingmapingmarker23.MapsActivity"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</LinearLayout>
```

in your `Styles.xml`
Don't provide any action bar

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

in your  `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(){
        ----
        Toolbar customToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        getSupportActionbar.
        setSupportActionBar(customToolbar);
    }

}
```

That's how you enable your custom `AppBar`.

Comment: So I added your style line into my styles.xml file but in the MapsActivity.java the 'setSupportActionbar' remainds red. Trying to run the app: Error:(40, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setSupportActionbar(Toolbar)

Comment: in your activity, import `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` instead of `android.widget.Toolbar`

Comment: I aldready do import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar; (see my 4th line of code)

Comment: can you update your code and let me know at which position are your calling that mehtod?

Comment: Code's updated - in the MapsActivitySheet under the first @Override (its a bit weird formatted here ^^)

Comment: an update has been made in my answer, kindly copy the code. Thanks

Comment: Added your code, red setSupportActionbar rests - maybe setActionbar ?

Comment: Oh!! Yea, Coz you are extending `FragmentActivity` 
Try it and let me know, thanks

Comment: Extend `AppCompatActivity` since it extends `FragmentActivity` internally.

Comment: 'did so, you can see the Track Race above. The code for the toolbar in the activity.java is now final Toolbar customToolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); - as AndroidStudio said

Comment: Try this theme then 
`Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: Hi, it's setSupportAction**B**ar(customToolbar); not setSupportAction**b**ar(customToolbar);
My bad!

Comment: Now it works - you're truly my hero! One question there is furthermore: the toolbar is now on the top, even when it's written in the .xml under the toolbar: 'android:layout_gravity="bottom" - why that?

Comment: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` add this to your `<..Toolbar..>`

Comment: Hi, kindly mark it as useful so that other users won't have to spend their time on this code. Thanks :)

Comment: In the .xml right? It doesn't change. AS sais there is invalid layout params

Comment: Well change your main layout to `<RelativeLayout>`

Comment: I don't get an error - the app bar is just on the top. But now somehow the map won't work - without any changes from my side. I've had that already more than once. May I write you later, when the map will work again?

Comment: Since newly I get the following error: E/GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-9808-0] bindTextureImage: error binding external image: 0x501 - I have no clue about that. In the web there are people who say that this is something from googles side, because they're updating something. Furthermore, my Toolbar is still on top

Comment: It means your Android Studio is not able to `bind` the image i.e. the one you want to use. Try any other image, are you getting the same error?

Comment: The problem is, that is not an image - it's a map imported from GoogleMaps. I do have an API-Key. The application is based on a preset for a google maps acitivty directly from android studio

Comment: Oh, I accidentally mixed your case with someone else's case. My bad.
So did you fix it?

Comment: No problem and no, I couldn't fix it

Comment: Do you know, what the issue is with the error/stack Trace (in red) '17711-18029/com.example.testingmapingmarker23 E/GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-17711-0] bindTextureImage: error binding external image: 0x501'

Comment: Sorry mate! No idea :/
Can I have your email id? I'll contact you if I'll ever get any answer :)

Comment: you can delete it now :)

Answer (score 2):

you have an error in xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/android"
    android:layout_height="1920dp"
    android:layout_widht="1080dp">
```

there is a typo mistake, change `width`

```
    android:layout_width="1080dp">
```

your stack trace specifies: `You must supply a layout_width attribute.`

**EDIT**

According to your new stack trace:

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this
>   activity.

You need to add `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` to your `application` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

**or**
if you have `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file then
change your `styles.xml` with `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">`

Comment: I wonder how the AS compiled the code in the first place, lol

Comment: if it still crashes, please add the new error stack trace

Comment: @FirozMemon it still crashes, you can see the updated Stack Trace above